# How to run a remote Python program from Windows command prompt

Tags: python, remote-server

I have an app on my website, and I run it with Python from the Windows Command Prompt.

When I try opening it like this,

```
python http://www.erickwilts.nl/apps/app.py
```

it says:

```
python: can't open file 'http://www.erickwilts.nl/apps/app.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You may need ssh to get to it.  Do you want to run the program locally or on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really wanted is to execute the file on the webserver itself. Luckily, I had help from some more experienced guys, who helped me on installing python on the webserver en executing my script from my own computer using ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Since the resource is located on webserver, you must download it first.
You can do it with `urllib2`

```
import urllib2
exec(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.erickwilts.nl/apps/app.py").read())
```

executing scripts like this is ***really dangerous*** though.

Comment: this will only work if they dont have cgi executing .py files also

Comment: I hope it's a lot less dangerous if I put the files there myself, right? :)